# How to get entities in a many-to-many relationship that do NOT have a corresponding linked entity with DQL and Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, many-to-many, dql

I have a standard **many-to-many** relationship set up. Entity A can have many of Entity B, and *vice versa*.

I'm trying to get a list of all Entity A that do NOT have any corresponding Entity B. In SQL, I'd run a query like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM entity_a a LEFT JOIN a_b r ON r.AID = a.id WHERE r.BID IS NULL
```

In this query, a_b is the linking table.

I'm trying to write a DQL statement (or use some other method) to get the same result, but the following does not work:

```
SELECT s FROM VendorMyBundle:EntityA s LEFT JOIN VendorMyOtherBundle:EntityB u WHERE u IS NULL
```

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I have to underline that usually you should JOIN on the property of the entity (i.e. **s**), e.g. instead of:

```
SELECT s FROM VendorMyBundle:EntityA s 
  LEFT JOIN VendorMyOtherBundle:EntityB u WHERE u IS NULL
```

you should have something like:

```
SELECT s FROM VendorMyBundle:EntityA s 
  LEFT JOIN s.mylistofb u WHERE u IS NULL
```

where I'm supposing that in entity A you have defined your relationship as:

```
class A{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\EntityB")
     * @JoinTable(name="as_bs",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     **/
    private $mylistofb;
```

This stated, if the query is not working yet, then try the following:

```
SELECT s FROM VendorMyBundle:EntityA s
  WHERE SIZE(s.mylistofb) < 1
```

It is simplest than the previous and also comes from the [official docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) (i.e. see "phonenumbers example").

Comment: Thanks for that! This solved the problem.

I'm still very used to SQL, not DQL, so some of these syntactic differences trip me up.

Comment: @Uthr It's the same for me.