# How do I create an efficient DQL statement, to match my efficient SQL when doing a simple LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I can craft a simple SQL that returns `1` when there is an item with requested `id` and corresponding `model` that matches `FS-%`, and `0` otherwise.

But when I try to write it as DQL, I fail in all spectacular ways.  See `EXPLAIN` results below.

**Question:**  How do I write an efficient DQL?

### SQL (efficient)

```
select count(*) 
from item 
left join product on item.product_id = product.id 
where item.id=2222 and product.model like "FS-%";
```

Using Explain:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item    | const | PRIMARY,product_id | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | product | const | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

### DQL (NOT efficient)

```
 $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('count(i)')
        ->from(Item::class, 'i')
        ->leftJoin(Product::class, 'p')
        ->where('i.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('p.model like :model')
        ->setParameter('id', 2222)
        ->setParameter('model', 'FS-%')
        ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

Resulting SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM item i0_ LEFT JOIN product p1_
        ON (i0_.id = 409264 AND p1_.model LIKE 'FS-%');
```

Using Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i0_   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 276000 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p1_   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    564 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note:  I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/25887143/2883328 to help me write the DQL.

Comment: If you are happy with sql then use sql.  $em->getConnection will return a thin wrapper over pdo.  As you have discovered, dql really wants to deal with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case I would have tried this query:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('count(i)')
        ->from(Item::class, 'i')
        ->leftJoin(Product::class, 'p', 'WITH', 'i.product = p.id')
        ->where('i.id = :id')
        ->andWhere('p.model like :model')
        ->setParameter('id', 2222)
        ->setParameter('model', 'FS-%')
        ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

change product in `i.product` to your property name